# Python loop multiplicates items

Tags: python, list

I'm having a very easy problem and I really don't understand why this is happening.

Im learning Python through the website codewars. One of the questions is to separate a sentence and order it by a number that contain each word. For example, if the sentence is `"Matias3 I1 a2m"` the program should return `"I1 a2m Matias3"` because of the order of the numbers that contain each word.

This is the code I'm using. It is very simple, but when I assign the new order `y[p] = ...` the program multiplicates the registers. If I remove that line, the registers are ok and I don't know why.

```
sentence="is2 Thi1s T4est 3a" #Example of sentence
x=sentence.split(" ") #I create an array with all the words
y= x #I create a second array (y). This is the one I will order by the numbers of the words

for i in range(len(x)): #I make a loop for the array x
  print("i: "+str(i)) 
  for j in range(len(x[i])): #I make a look for each character of the word
    print(" i:"+str(i)+" j:"+str(j)+" "+x[i])
    if x[i][j:j+1].isnumeric(): #If the character is a number, then Id like to put that word in the 
                                #that number position in the y array (of course is the position-1)
      p=int(x[i][j:j+1])-1 # This is the position that the word should be
      y[p]=x[i]  # When I assing y[] to the correct position (I want that the position i                     
                 # becomes the position p, the program get lost)

print(y)
```

Comment: `y = x` does not make a second list, it just gives you a second reference to the __same__ list. Any changes you make to `y` will happen to `x`, `y = x.copy()` will give you a second list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, the `y = x` gives you a reference, not a copy of the same list. You need to do `y = x.copy()` to get the wanted result.

This behaviour is described e.g. in the [copy module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html):

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one can change one copy without changing the other.

But in addition, this function gives you also the result:

```
print(sorted(sentence.split(), key=lambda e: min(e)))
```

As you can see, there is already a built-in function [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) that does everything you want. All you need to do is provide your own sort function. The provided sort function searches for the min-value of the words in the sentence. This is done by the built-in function [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min).

To complete the task, you have to do one last step: Printing the list as a string again. This can be done via [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), see:

```
>>> sentence = "Matias3 I1 a2m"
>>> print(" ".join(sorted(sentence.split(), key=lambda e: min(e))))
I1 a2m Matias3
```

Answer (score 0):

What @lain Shelvington said is totally correct. But you may try some code more pythonic below.

```
sentence="is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"

raw_words_list = sentence.split(' ')
raw_words_dict = {}

for word in raw_words_list:
    for char in word:
        if char.isnumeric():
            raw_words_dict[char] = word

print([raw_words_dict[key] for key in sorted(raw_words_dict.keys())])
```